# Voip services (PKPush) delegate methods not being called

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, voip

I am trying to set up a PKPushRegistry so I can receive VOIP service pushes but my delegates aren't firing. I am successfully get back a devicetoken so I know that the first part of the process is working. Also, my server has the proper certificates for both kind of pushes.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, PKPushRegistryDelegate {

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

            self.voipRegistration()
    }

    func voipRegistration() {
        let mainQueue = DispatchQueue.main
        let voipRegistry: PKPushRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: mainQueue)
        voipRegistry.delegate = self
        voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [PKPushType.voIP]
    }


    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didInvalidatePushTokenFor type: PKPushType) {
        //
    }

    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType) {
        //
    }

    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate pushCredentials: PKPushCredentials, for type: PKPushType) {
        //
    }


    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        //
    }
```

Comment: in my case didUpdate did not called for first time when device need permission for push. but there is device token print in console by pushkit. when i send push by this token push is coming during app is foreground, background and even closed. in the situation if i re-launch the app didUpdate being called working fine. but still i need to record device token in didUpdate during pushkit register.. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Apple took VOIP out of the background modes so I added it manually and it worked

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
    <string>voip</string>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```